# How to set the session time out in servlet

Tags: servlets

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);

    if (session == null) {
        String forwardTo = "/jsp/login.jsp?status=session";
        ServletContext servletContext = filterConfig.getServletContext();
        javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher dispatcher = servletContext
                .getRequestDispatcher(forwardTo);
        if (dispatcher != null) {
            try {
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

istead of 30 i want to get a user preference time. Here i tried setmaxinactive interval() method but i dont know where i have to use that

Answer (score 0):

After getting the session object, you can add this attribute:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60);
```

Comment: No the 60 minutes is constant. But I have to put a dynamic values

Comment: The 60 is just an example of changing the default value in runtime, in contrast to using web.xml which is globally configured for all sessions. please explain what do you mean by 'user preference time' ?

Comment: The user has to be mention the time for session timeout..
For eg.,
If The user prefers 10 min as 'session time out' The session must be expire with in 10 minutes